# Macro to hide rows isn't hiding every single one

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote two macros, `HideRowsInSOW()` and HideRowsInSOW2()` to hide any blank cells in two tables in the same spreadsheet. Each cell references a corresponding cell on the next spreadsheet, Services. There is one row colored gray that is the header of each section in the two tables with 10 white rows for details underneath each gray row.

My first macro successfully hides all the empty white rows but not the gray rows. If there isn't a value in the gray cell, I need it to be hidden just like the white rows are being hidden. The second one keeps crashing Excel.

```
    Sub HideRowsInSOW()
    For Each c In Range("B29:B706")
    If c.Value = "0" Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next
    End Sub

Another macro I tried is the following (there is another similar macro for the rows in the second table). This macro was much worse, like I said, it keeps crashing Excel:

If Sheets("SOW").Range("B28") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B49") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("49:69").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("49:69").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B70") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("70:90").Hidden = True
   Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("70:90").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B91") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("91:111").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("91:111").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B112") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("112:132").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("112:132").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B133") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("133:153").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("133:153").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B154") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("154:174").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("154:174").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B175") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("175:195").Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("175:195").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B196") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("196:216").Hidden = True
   Else
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("196:216").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B217") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("217:237").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("217:237").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B238") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("238:258").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("238:258").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B259") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("259:279").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("259:279").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B280") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("280:300").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("280:300").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B301") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("301:321").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("301:321").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B322") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("322:342").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("322:342").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B343") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("343:363").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("322:342").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B364") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("364:384").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("364:384").Hidden = False
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B385") = " " Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("385:405").Hidden = True
   Else
         Worksheets("SOW").Rows("385:405").Hidden = False
    End If
```

The first macro I used is assigned to a button. When I click on the button, all the white rows with no values hide but the gray rows which act as headers aren't. The differences between the gray and white rows are the color of the cells, that the gray cells reference gray cells on the second spreadsheet which are drop downs that can be edited, and that some of the columns in the gray rows are merged and centered as well as wrapped. Not sure if any of these differences might affect it.

Comment: Which row has header ? 28 ?

Comment: Yeah, 28, 49, 70, 91, 112, 133, 154, 175, 196, 217, 238, 259, 280, 301, 322, 343, 371, 392, 413, 434, 455, 476, 497, 518, 539, 560, 581, 602, 623, 644, 665, 686. I'll edit my post, the macro covers two tables.

Comment: Also, @Mikku, I wrote the company's name in the same color as the background of the cell in the cells in between the two tables. Sorry for not thinking to add this or all the rows that act as headers in my original explanation.

Comment: Try changing this `If c.Value = "0" Then` to `If Len(c.Value) < 1 Then`

Comment: That made my workbook crash two times for some reason. I'll include another code I tried using that also didn't work in my original post.

Comment: when hiding or deleteing rows you need to work from the bottom up

Comment: I tried by using ("B706:B29") for the range but nothing happened when I clicked on the macro button, @alowflyingpig.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in reverse:

```
Sub HideRowsInSOW()

    For i = 706 to 29 step -1
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "0" Then
            Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Interestingly, trying it in reverse hid all of the blank gray rows but none of the blank white rows. Should I combine your sub and mine?

Comment: Never mind, I tried calling the two subs but it just made my workbook crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out via trail and error of changing up some of the variables in the macro. What ended up working was changing each `" "` to `0` in the first line of code in each If statement in the second macro. I could've sworn I had already tried doing this but I guess not if it's now working but wasn't before.

For example:

```
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B28") = 0 Then
          Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = True
        End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B49") = 0 Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("49:69").Hidden = True
     End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B70") = 0 Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("70:90").Hidden = True
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B91") = 0 Then
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows("91:111").Hidden = True
    End If
```

And so on.